# Inner join in spark dataframes not getting proper columns as expected

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am doing inner join for the in spark dataframes similar coversion of sql query

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.aid,a.DId,a.BM,a.BY,b.TO FROM GetRaw a 
INNER JOIN DF_SD b WHERE a.aid = b.aid AND a.DId= b.DId AND a.BM= b.BM AND a.BY = b.BY"
```

I am converting as

```
val Pr = DF_SD.select("aid","DId","BM","BY","TO").distinct()
.join(GetRaw,GetRaw.("aid") <=> DF_SD("aid")
&& GetRaw.("DId")  <=> DF_SD("DId")
&& DF_SD,GetRaw.("BM")  <=> DF_SD("BM")
&& DF_SD,GetRaw.("BY")  <=> DF_SD("BY"))
```

My Output Table contains columns

```
"aid","DId","BM","BY","TO","aid","DId","BM","BY"
```

Can any one correct where I am doing wrong

Comment: @Anji You should correct your reference code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Just use SELECT of distincts after join:

```
val Pr = DF_SD.join(GetRaw,Seq("aid","DId","BM","BY"))
.select("aid","DId","BM","BY","TO").distinct
```

Answer (score 0):

you can mention column names in sequence, which is correct way of handling this problem..

pls see https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/faq/join-two-dataframes-duplicated-column.html

```
  val Pr = DF_SD.join(GetRaw,Seq("aid","DId","BM","BY"))
.dropDuplicates() //optionally, if you want to drop duplicate rows from the dataframe then 
    Pr.show();
```